# Как выровнять по высоте 3 дива?

Tags: css

Есть 3 дива. Пример на рисунке.
[image]
Как средствами CSS можно выровнять высоту блоков, чтобы они заканчивались на одном уровне?
**UPD:**

Результат должен быть таким:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример с помощью табличной верстки

```css
.one {
  border: 2px dotted red;
  width: 250px;
}
.two {
  border: 2px dotted blue;
  width: 250px;
}
.three {
  border: 2px dotted orange;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="one">
      orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean lobortis ornare blandit. Donec sapien risus, volutpat vel nulla ac, porta condimentum nunc. Vestibulum hendrerit ac enim at malesuada. Etiam a neque eros. Maecenas sagittis tellus nisl. Etiam
      posuere bibendum fringilla. Mauris tortor velit, s tortor velit,elit. nunc. Vestibulum hendrerit ac enim at malesuada. Etiam a neque eros. Maecenas sagittis tellus nisl. Etiam posuere bibendum fringilla. Mauris tortor velit, s tortor velit,elit.
      fringilla. Mauris tortor velit, sollicitudin id arcu ac, cursus imperdiet quam. Etiam bibendum diam fringilla magna condimentum, quis vestibulum elit cursus. Sed molestie ipsum et mi sollicitudin cursus.
    </td>
    <td class="two">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean lobortis ornare blandit. Donec sapien risus, volutpat vel nulla ac, porta condimentum nunc. Vestibulum hendrerit ac enim at malesuada. Etiam a neque eros. Maecenas sagittis tellus nisl.
      Etiam posuere bibendum fringilla. Mauris tortor velit, sollicitudin id arcu ac, cursus imperdiet quam. Etiam bibendum diam fringilla magna condimentum, quis vestibulum elit cursus. Sed molestie ipsum et mi sollicitudin cursus.</td>
    <td class="three">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean lobortis ornare blandit. Donec sapien risus, volutpat vel nulla ac, porta condimentum llicitudin id arcu ac, cursus imperdiet quam. Etiam bibendum diam fringilla magna condimentum, quis
      vestibulum elit cursus. Sed molestie ipsum et mi sollicitudin cursus.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: А чем это поможет? max-haight - это, насколько мне известно - максимальная высота, больше которой див не расширится. Как это свойство поможет здесь, я не понимаю. Возможно Вы имели ввиду min-height? Ну тоже не подходит.

Comment: Прошу прощения, ошибся, имел ввиду min-height, да. Ну раз и это не помогает, тогда может просто жестко задать высоту не пробовали?

Comment: Ну дело в том, что не жёсткая высота, не мин-хэйт не помогают, так как текст из базы выводится. И мы не знаем заранее, сколько текста в в каждом из бловов будет.

Comment: И вам надо только чтобы они просто "заканчивались на одном уровне" ? Или надо чтобы они находились на одном уровне (и сверху и снизу) ?

Comment: Ну естественно, чтобы и начинались, и заканчивались. Добавил картинку в вопросе.

Comment: Ну тогда как вариант можно сделать это табличной версткой, это 100% прокатит.
<table>
<tr>
<td>Тут текст первого блока</td>
<td>Тут текст второго блока</td>
</tr>
</table>

Comment: Обновил ответ, посмотрите.

Comment: Ну конечно на дивах желательно. Но на крайняк можно и таблицы.

Answer (score 2):

Если вас не очень волнует совместимость со старыми браузерами, то советую использовать [flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) ([подробнее](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/)). Прекрасный инструмент, который решает множество проблем с layout-ом, в том числе и вашу. [Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/WM8tx/1/).

Comment: А с какими браузерами совместим?

Comment: Извиняюсь, поддержка пока только в Firefox(>18) и Chrome(>22). IE и Safari поддерживают только устаревший черновик с другим синтаксисом (display: flexbox). Так что пока это не вариант.

Comment: На дворе 2019-й, и сейчас это, пожалуй, лучший вариант.

Answer (score 2):

достаточно задать родителю `display: table` а ребенку `display: table-cell`.
Нужно не забывать, что `margin` в таблицах не работает.

```css
.parent{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.child {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: tomato;
  width: 33.3333%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi inventore similique deserunt dolor. Repellat suscipit, magni enim quo incidunt porro culpa nemo soluta, expedita aspernatur cumque quidem vitae, minima sequi! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi inventore similique deserunt dolor. Repellat suscipit, magni enim quo incidunt porro culpa nemo soluta, expedita aspernatur cumque quidem vitae, minima sequi!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi inventore similique deserunt dolor. Repellat suscipit, magni enim quo incidunt porro culpa nemo soluta, expedita aspernatur cumque quidem vitae, minima sequi!</div>
  <div class="child">Ab sint autem porro delectus consectetur. Optio corporis consequatur eveniet, debitis iusto incidunt. Facilis veritatis voluptatibus quibusdam dolorem sed illo sit vero asperiores commodi. Suscipit, adipisci, veritatis. Nam, blanditiis, voluptate?</div>
  <div class="child">Provident aliquam, sunt, minus labore cum est quae in qui officiis impedit accusamus necessitatibus odit, amet harum delectus. Enim delectus, aspernatur quia nulla nam est quo dolore quisquam consectetur nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam, velit! Provident aliquam, sunt, minus labore cum est quae in qui officiis impedit accusamus necessitatibus odit, amet harum delectus. Enim delectus, aspernatur quia nulla nam est quo dolore quisquam consectetur nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam, velit!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

JS подойдет?

```
// Назначьте всем div-ам одинаковый класс и передайте его в эту функцию.
function alignmentByHeight(classname) {
    var divs = $("div ."+classname);
    var max = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<divs.length; i++) {
        max = Math.max(max, $(divs[i]).height());
    }
    $(divs).css('min-height', max+'px');
}
```

Comment: Нет, яваскрипт не подходит.

Answer (score 0):

А можно сделать и совместимый со старыми браузерами вариант (без таблиц).
Вот пример на [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/deynK/1/)

Comment: Не хочу тебя расстраивать, но кажется у тебя в примере текст выезжает за пределы дива, не так ли?

Comment: Забыл проверить случай, когда намеренно сильно сжимают окошко jsFiddle по ширине. Поправил код: (http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/deynK/1/)